# RStudio IDE Assignment Shortcut Issue

Tags: rstudio

I am writting a .RMD document (R notebook) and I must have hit some sort of key combination that has changed the assigment operator inserted by `ALT+-`.  Now instead of the `<-` operator it (`ALT+-`) inserts `=` .

Steps I have used to attempt to diagnose/resolve:

- Closed out document and reopened- still has the problem
- Tried shortcut in consul and different document- still inserts `=` not `<-`
- Closed out of RStudio and reopened- no change
- Reset all keyboard shortcuts- no change

Additional information:

- Rstudio version: Version 1.0.136
- OS: Windows 10
- Have posted on Rstudio
- Googled- only can find how to use that shortcut but not how to change the operator

Comment: Resolved:
Issue appears to be operator error.  Appears that `alt+-` in a code chunk does `<-` but elsewhere in that document, as well as when you click arbitrarily in other documents, `alt+-` yeilds `=`.